# Dynamically change styled component based on state AND index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, render, styled-components

So I have a list that was returned from an API request (not important)
lets call it `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];`

Now, inside render(), I have something like the following

```
render(){
  <Wrapper>
    {list.map((i) => {
      return (<Button id = {i} onClick = {this.customFunc.bind(this, i)} />)
    }
  </Wrapper>
}
```

Now, I have another list, lets call it `list_check = [false...]` (for all 7 elements listed above)

Assume that `customFunc` changes the respective button id in `list_check` from false to true.

e.g. if I clicked button 1 `(id = 1)` then `list_check` becomes `[false, true, false...]`

** Now my problem is: I have 2 styled components, `Button` and `Button_Selected`,
how can i dynamically change between the 2 styled components so that if that unique button is clicked (change `list_check[index] = true`), the element becomes `Button_Selected` instead of `Button` (The entire list is initalized as `Button` since all elements are `false`)

Just to make it clear:
Both arrays are located in `this.state` and by 2 styled components I mean there exists

```
const Button = styled.div`
  //styling here
`;
```

and

```
const Button_Selected = Button.extend`
 //Small styling change to differentiate between selected and not selected
`;
```

edit: all answers are great! too bad I can only select one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just save the component to another variable.

```
this.state.list_check.map((item, i) => {
    const NecessaryButton = item ? SelectedButton : Button;
    return <NecessaryButton onClick={() => this.makeSelected(i)}>Normal Button</NecessaryButton>
})
```

You can see a live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y8jxzk?file=index.js).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can return 2 buttons based on conditional rendering .You can also pass props to your `styled Button` so that based on props you can change your styles.

```
   render(){
  <Wrapper>
    {list.map((i) => {
      return (<Button id = {i} isSelected={this.state.list_check[i]} onClick = {this.customFunc.bind(this, i)} />)
    }
  </Wrapper>
}
```

And in your styled Button:

```
  const Button = styled.div`
  styleName: ${props => props.isSelected ? 'styling_if_Selected' : 'styling_if_not_selected'};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to have a single Button component and handle in the state if it was selected. Depending on this state you could switch classes.
Example:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isSelected: false
    };

    handleClick() {
        //Here we will set the state change and call the onClick function passed by props
        this.setState({isSelected: !this.state.isSelected}, () => { this.props.onClick(); });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button 
                class={this.state.isButtonSelected ? "classBtnSelected" : "classBtnDefault"} 
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Still, if you want to switch components you can use state to control if it was selected and do a conditional rendering. Example:

```
render(){
  <Wrapper>
    {list.map((i) => {
      return (this.state.isSelected 
         ? <Button id={i} onClick = {this.customFunc.bind(this, i)} /> 
         : <Button_Selected id={i} onClick = {this.customFunc.bind(this, i)} />)
    }
  </Wrapper>
}
```